# Make Objective-C header files with "Project" visibility accessible in Swift files in the same framework

Tags: swift, objective-c, module, header-files, visibility

I am working on an Objective-C framework and trying to add Swift features to it. To do that I need to use some protocols and enums declared in Objective-C that have a visibility level of **"Project"**. I created a modulemap file for the private files but couldn't find a solution to **"Project"** visibility.